# the most natural approach to solve an elliptic PDE in R^n

Tags: elliptic-pde

Let $n \geq 1, \lambda >0, f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $b: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector field satisfying $\mbox{div}(b) \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. What would be the most natural approach to solve the following equation: $\lambda u -\frac{1}{2} \Delta u + b(x)\nabla u = f \quad \mbox{in} \quad \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Obvisously, when $\lambda$ is larger than $\| \mbox{div}(b) \|_{\infty}$ then Lax-Milgram theory can be applied to get a solution. But what can we say for $\lambda$ smaller than $\| \mbox{div}(b) \|_{\infty}$?

Comment: What do you mean by solving? Finding a closed form formula for a solution in terms of the parameters, showing unique solvability, solving the equation numerically, or something else?

Comment: I mean finding a function $u$ in an appropriate functional space satisfying the problem above.

Comment: does the question is still [on hold]?

Comment: Why it is closed? Could someone tell me where I can find a answer, please?

Comment: This is a fine question, but people have felt that it is not appropriate for this site. You should ask this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/ Or if you want, this question can also be migrated (moved) there.